# How can I get GNOME 3.0 Beta on Ubuntu 11.04 Alpha 1

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-unity, ubuntu-11.04

I've just installed Ubuntu 11.04 (Natty Narwwhal) Alpha 1 and I love the Unity GUI

Is it possible to download GNOME 3.0 on it as I like to try things early?

How do I change between the two?

Comment: Unity isn't GNOME 3.0, it's near 100% Canonical and Ubuntu.

Comment: I mean useing another window maneger instead of install Ubuntu 10.10 and adding GNOME 3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should download the GNOME 3 script from its website and then install it and change like normal